# Visual Basic error BC30456 'RED is not a member of 'COLOR'

Tags: vb.net, error-handling, colors

I dont know why but .net just showming me the error when i want to change richtextbox1.text color to red

```
    Private Sub RichTextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.TextChanged
    Dim theColor As System.Drawing.Color
    Dim loc As Int16
   the colour to red.
    If RichTextBox1.Text.Contains("CARD LOCKED") Then
        loc = RichTextBox1.Find("CARD LOCKED")
        RichTextBox1.Select(loc, 11)
        RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = COLOR.red   'ERROR
        RichTextBox1.ForeColor = COLOR.red       'ERRROR

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The most likely explanation is that you have used the name `Color` for something else (namespace, type, structure, etc) in your project. In that case, that use of `Color` will be interpreted to mean that rather than the `System.Drawing.Color` type. The fact that you have qualified the `System.Drawing.Color` type earlier in your code and those last two usages are "COLOR" rather than "Color" seem to support that. You need to either avoid name clashes in the first place or else qualify the usage of `Color` in those last two cases as for the first.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thx, but i serached for "COLOR", and found nothing with this name(vars, controls etc)

Comment: Hover the mouse cursor over it and see what it tells you . If you're VS version supports it, right-click on it and select 'Go To Definition' or 'Go To Implementation'. You may also be able to Ctrl+Click on it, although that may just be a ReSharper thing - I can never recall.

Comment: If you qualify it as `System.Drawing.Color` and it works then that guarantees that it's a name clash.  If you had simply not imported that namespace then the error would tell you that that type wasn't defined.

Comment: When the casing is all wrong (COLOR instead of Color) then you pretty much *know* that you are not actually using the System.Drawing.Color type.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i did what you recommended, it says " IMPLEMENTATION  NOT FOUND"

Comment: Seems like its really some vb.net thing, maybe some error with vb.designer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change COLOR.red with System.Drawing.Color.Red

Also, you should change the 'loc' type to Integer to avoid implicit conversions.